# Using tee to append string to a file and also use it as replacement for a pattern in another file

Tags: awk, sed, tee

I have the following code:

```
cat file | grep example | sed 's/http/https/' >> report.txt
```

Output of that command:

```
https://example.com/page/index.html
```

This will add a link, with HTTPS, to the file. I would like, however, for that same output to also replace "URL" in a second file.

Content of the second file:

```
TEXT TEXT
TEXT

URL

TEXT TEXT
```

Desired change in second file:

```
TEXT TEXT
TEXT

https://example.com/page/index.html

TEXT TEXT
```

Is this possible?

P.S.: I can't repeat the command again, as it is actually not a simple cat but an upload process that starts the command.

Comment: Yes, it's possible... please expand on that replacement; btw, you don't need `cat` and `grep`.

Comment: I have a second file in json that contains the text URL, that I would like to replace by what comes out of the code I posted. Makes sense? :/

Comment: replace ` >> report.txt ` by `tee -a report.txt second_file.txt`  ?

Comment: note that tee is intended to write/append multiple file at once, not to edit.

Comment: The post was improperly formatted. Changed the post to better reflect what I have and what I'm aiming for. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: That's correct. I've changed the output to make it easier.

Comment: How can you get that output from the first command?  The string `URL` doesn't show up in it anywhere, so it shouldn't get to the `sed`

Comment: You're absolutely right. It was my bad trying to edit the post. Was much easier if I could just paste the code itself, but I can't. I've edited the post again. 

Damn, really sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, you don't need `cat` and `grep` as `sed` alone can do it:

```
sed '/URL/!d;s/http/&s/'
```

Anyway, assuming you run a chain of commands that produce a single line of output you can do:

```
... | tee -a report.txt | sed 's|[\&/]|\\&|g;s|.*|s/URL/&/g|' | sed -f- -i infile.json
```

This appends the output to `report.txt` but also pipes it to `sed` which turns it into a `sed` command which is then piped to another `sed` which will edit the `.json` file in-place.

Comment: Worked exactly as I was hoping! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the short answer to a short question:

```
cat file | grep URL | sed 's/http/https/' | tee -a report.txt | while read $LINE; do
    sed --in-place -e "s·URL·$LINE·" thejsonfile.json
done
```

Make sure to replace all three `·` in the `sed` script by some character not contained in `$LINE`, or leave it as `·` (middle dot).

EDIT: I've just learned from a different question, that piping into a `while read` loop is considered bad practice, because of performance and other reasons. It'll get your job done, thou, so I leave this here.

Comment: thejsonfile.json is getting the URL removed, and nothing added. I also made a mistake regarding the output, as the output is:

This is the public address: https://example.com/page/index.html

I've edited my question. Can this be the reason your solution isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/example/s/http/&s/p' file | tee -a report.txt |\
sed -e 'G;s/$/./;G;s/$/wq/;h;s|.*|/URL/c|;G' | ed -s - json_file
```

We build an `ed` code based on the first output and use that to edit the json file.